# golang/python zlib difference

Tags: python, go, zlib

Debugging differences between Python's zlib and golang's zlib. Why don't the following have the same results?

`compress.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "compress/flate"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)


func compress(source string) []byte {
    w, _ := flate.NewWriter(nil, 7)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    w.Reset(buf)
    w.Write([]byte(source))
    w.Close()

    return buf.Bytes()
}


func main() {
    example := "foo"
    compressed := compress(example)
    fmt.Println(compressed)
}
```

`compress.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import zlib


def compress(source):
    # golang zlib strips header + checksum
    compressor = zlib.compressobj(7, zlib.DEFLATED, -15)
    compressor.compress(source)
    # python zlib defaults to Z_FLUSH, but 
    # https://golang.org/pkg/compress/flate/#Writer.Flush
    # says "Flush is equivalent to Z_SYNC_FLUSH"
    return compressor.flush(zlib.Z_SYNC_FLUSH)


def main():
    example = u"foo"
    compressed = compress(example)
    print(list(bytearray(compressed)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Results

```
$ go version
go version go1.7.3 darwin/amd64
$ go build compress.go
$ ./compress
[74 203 207 7 4 0 0 255 255]
$ python --version
$ python 2.7.12
$ python compress.py
[74, 203, 207, 7, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255]
```

The Python version has `0` for the fifth byte, but the golang version has `4` -- what's causing the different output?

Comment: zlib uses a DEFLATE implementation, but flate and zlib aren't the same. Here you're closing the flate stream in go, while in python you're only flushing. If you change the Go code to `Flush()` the output will be the same. Also note that different implementations aren't guaranteed to produce the same binary output, they only are guaranteed to produce compatible output.

Comment: @jimb: https://golang.org/pkg/compress/flate/ says "Package flate implements the DEFLATE compressed data format, described in RFC 1951..." which seems to contradict the first sentence or I'm misunderstanding you (or the docs =)). Similarly, https://golang.org/pkg/compress/flate/#Writer.Close claims to flush the writer and adding an explicit `w.Flush()` after the `w.Write(...)` line adds more padding/checksum bytes. Would you mind providing a little more detail as there's something I'm clearly not following?

Comment: This output matches the python output: https://play.golang.org/p/_SCAspI3Mq. I don't understand what you find contradicting; you're using zlib in python which _uses_ DEFLATE internally to produce a zlib format output, whereas your Go example is using a DEFLATE implementation directly. I don't know if you can get the python zlib library to output the raw, complete DEFLATE stream, but trying to get different libraries to output byte-for-byte matches of compressed data doesn't seem useful or maintainable.

Comment: > This output matches the python output: play.golang.org/p/_SCAspI3Mq 
ah, thanks for clarifying (I'd misread "change" as "add").  
> I don't know if you can get the python zlib library to output the raw, complete DEFLATE stream, but trying to get different libraries to output byte-for-byte matches of compressed data doesn't seem useful or maintainable.
Fair enough,

Comment: (continued - ran into edit time limits when trying to reformat)
I'm having trouble with the round trip and was trying to produce a simpler example by isolating the compression bit. Thanks for the suggestions and help--if you feel like turning your comments into an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output from the python example isn't a "complete" stream, its just flushing the buffer after compressing the first string. You can get the same output from the Go code by replacing `Close()` with `Flush()`:

https://play.golang.org/p/BMcjTln-ej

```
func compress(source string) []byte {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w, _ := flate.NewWriter(buf, 7)
    w.Write([]byte(source))
    w.Flush()

    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

However, you are comparing output from zlib in python, which uses DEFLATE internally to produce a zlib format output, and `flate` in Go, which *is* a DEFLATE implementation. I don't know if you can get the python zlib library to output the raw, complete DEFLATE stream, but trying to get different libraries to output byte-for-byte matches of compressed data doesn't seem useful or maintainable. The output of the compression libraries is only guaranteed to be compatible, not identical.

Comment: Whoops, sorry it took so long for me to accept answer, missed notification. Thanks for writing it up nicely. =)