# zlib difference between golang and python

Tags: python, go, zlib

Go:
package main

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/hex"
    "compress/zlib"
)
func zlibCompress(src []byte) []byte {
    var in bytes.Buffer
    w, _ := zlib.NewWriterLevel(&in, zlib.DefaultCompression)
    w.Write(src)
    w.Close()
    return in.Bytes()
}
func main(){
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(zlibCompress([]byte{'1'})))
}
```

Output:

```
789c3204040000ffff00320032
```

Python:

```
compressed_data = zlib.compress(b"1")
print(compressed_data.hex())
```

Output:

```
789c33040000320032
```

What is the defference bettween "3204040000ffff" and "330400" ?
I googled "zlib 0000ffff" and found that "0000ffff" is the flag of flush.

because I can not modify the server-side, so I must make my go project fit the server-side. I tried pass the data compresed by golang to the server-side,but the server  refuse it because it can't decompress the data.

How to get python-style result in golang?

Comment: Can you explain why your zlib file needs to match exactly? 4 extra bytes seems not worth worrying about?

Comment: @Max ,I don't have the source of server-side, but I have a client written by python that sends data compressed by zlib.compress  to the server,and the server accept it successfully,so I  want to use golang to rewrite the client. Original data is same, if I use python's zlib to compress the original data and then send to the server, the server accept, but if I use golang's zlib to do the same thing, the server occur a error "decompress error". so I think the server only accept "python-style" zlib ?

Comment: I tried using python to decompress the data that compressed by golang, everything is OK. so maybe the server is not written by python .

Comment: If it is indeed an extra flush, that really should make no difference.  I'm not sure how you would suppress it without like, rewriting Go's zlib module.

Comment: @Max Thank you all the same, I try to find a package who provides zlib without Z_SYNC_FLUSH

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893411/golang-python-zlib-difference

Comment: @JimB Thank you. I have found the 3rd-party package https://github.com/4kills/go-zlib ,which provides the same result with python.

Comment: That's probably because it links to the same c library as python. Note that you cannot rely on the exact same byte-for-byte output between implementations, which are only guaranteed to be compatible, not identical. These could still differ if linked to different versions of the zlib library on different systems.

Comment: Oh, that library is linking to a pre-compiled binary blob, which you have no idea where or how it was compiled. I would be wary of using that at all.

Comment: @JimB oh,I didn't notice that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an empty stored block was added by Golang. No, this doesn't matter for you. Both will decompress to the same thing. Do not worry about getting the same result. Both outputs are valid.

The first one:

```
! infgen 3.0 output
!
zlib
!
fixed
literal '1
end
!
last
stored
end
!
adler
```

and the second:

```
! infgen 3.0 output
!
zlib
!
last
fixed
literal '1
end
!
adler
```

Golang is adding the stored block as a last block to end the deflate stream, whereas Python took into account that that was all of the data, so it made the first block the last block.